# What is the method to delete the custom cell from UITableView?

Tags: iphone, xcode

i have a custom cell i want to delete it when a button is clicked situated on the custom cell itself.how do i achieve this. someone help i am stuck at this from many days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do this instead of using the standard delete behavior, but...

First you need to know the `indexPath` for the cell on which that button is being pressed.  So you have to wire the custom cell to receive the button action, and then call the table's `indexPathForCell` method with that cell to get the indexPath.

Once you have it, you put the indexPath inside an `NSArray` and pass it to the table's `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` method (and also choose the type of animation for removing the cell). This will also invoke the dataSource's `commitEditingStyle` method to let you delete the underlying data as well.

Keep in mind that by doing it this way, you're bypassing the two-step delete process that is built into the table -- where the user would normally request a delete and then have to confirm it. So for the sake of safety, you'll probably want to implement something like that yourself.

Also, the default behavior for swiping across a table cell is to bring up the delete button. You may want to override the `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method and return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` for that cell so it doesn't do the default thing.

Comment: could you please post a sample code for this. i still don't understand this